# add iteratively in z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to check the value of a, b, c, and if value 'a' equals to 1, 'x' is added one. We continue the process for values 'b' and 'c'.
So if a=1, b=1, c=1, the result of x should be 3.
if a=1, b=1, c=0, so the result of x should be 2.
Any methods to be implemented in z3?
The source code looks like this:

```py
from z3 import *

a, b, c = Ints('a b c')
x, y = Ints('x y')
s = Solver()
s.add(If(a==1, x=x + 1, y = y-1))
s.add(If(b==1, x=x + 1, y = y-1))
s.add(If(c==1, x=x + 1, y = y-1))
s.check()
print s.model()
```

Any suggestions about what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

This sort of "iterative" processing is usually modeled by unrolling the assignments and creating what's known as SSA form. (Static single assignment.) In this format, every variable is assigned precisely once, but can be used many times. This is usually done by some underlying tool as it is rather tedious, but you can do it by hand as well. Applied to your problem, it'd look something like:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

a, b, c = Ints('a b c')

x0, x1, x2, x3 = Ints('x0 x1 x2 x3')

s.add(x0 == 0)
s.add(x1 == If(a == 1, x0+1, x0))
s.add(x2 == If(b == 1, x1+1, x1))
s.add(x3 == If(c == 1, x2+1, x2))

# Following asserts are not part of your problem, but
# they make the output interesting
s.add(b == 1)
s.add(c == 0)

# Find the model
if s.check() == sat:
   m = s.model()
   print("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d, x=%d" % (m[a].as_long(), m[b].as_long(), m[c].as_long(), m[x3].as_long()))

else:
    print "no solution"
```

SSA transformation is applied to the variable `x`, creating as many instances as necessary to model the assignments. When run, this program produces:

```
a=0, b=1, c=0, x=1
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Which tools can do it automatically?

Comment: Mostly compilers, translators, verification engines, and alike. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form for details.

Answer (score 0):

Note that z3 has many functions. One you could use here is `Sum()` for the sum of a list. Inside the list you can put simple variables, but also expression. Here an example for both a simple and a more complex sum:

```
from z3 import *

a, b, c = Ints('a b c')
x, y = Ints('x y')
s = Solver()
s.add(a==1, b==0, c==1)
s.add(x==Sum([a,b,c]))
s.add(y==Sum([If(a==1,-1,0),If(b==1,-1,0),If(c==1,-1,0)]))
if s.check() == sat:
    print ("solution:", s.model())
else:
    print ("no solution possible")
```

Result:
    `solution: [y = 2, x = 2, c = 1, b = 0, a = 1]`

If your problem is more complex, using BitVecs instead of Ints can make it run a little faster.

edit: Instead of `Sum()` you could also simply use addition as in

s.add(x==a+b+c)
  s.add(y==If(a==1,-1,0)+If(b==1,-1,0)+If(c==1,-1,0))

`Sum()` makes sense towards readability when you have a longer list of variables, or when the variables already are in a list.

Comment: @alias: Do you think I properly understood the question?

Comment: I think your encoding is perfectly fine. It's impossible to tell what the intention of the original poster was, maybe they can opine. SSA is a general trick to handle such imperative looking programs, which I assumed he/she was dealing with in general. For specific instances, the simpler the coding, the better; of course.